# C++ object not found inside nested ListView in QML

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a ListView nested inside another ListView in my qml. Both the ListViews are being populated by a data models which I get from a C++ class `SelectRoomView`. This is the code for my qml file:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import Data.SelectRoomView 1.0
import "commons"


Page {
    id: pageSelectARoom

property alias currentPage: pageSelectARoom
property string propId

attachedObjects: [
    SelectRoomView {
        id: selRoom 
    }
]

onPropIdChanged: {
    selRoom.propId = propId;
}

Container {
    layout: StackLayout {
        orientation: LayoutOrientation.TopToBottom
    }

    background: Color.create("#FFFFFF")

    ScrollView{   
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
        objectName: "scrollView"                   

        ListView {
            id: ruleList
            dataModel: selRoom.modelRule

            listItemComponents: [   
                ListItemComponent {
                    id: outerList

                    Container{
                        Label {
                            id: outerLabel
                            text: ListItemData.ruleName
                            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
                            textStyle.color: Color.Black
                        }
                        Label{
                            id: outerId
                            text: ListItemData.ruleId
                            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
                            textStyle.color: Color.Black
                            visible: true
                        }

                        ListView{
                            id: roomList
                            dataModel: selRoom.modelRoom  //I get the message ReferenceError: Can't find the variable: selRoom
                            listItemComponents: [

                                ListItemComponent {
                                    id: innerList


                                    Label{
                                        id: innerLabel
                                        text: ListItemData.name
                                        textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
                                        textStyle.color: Color.Black

                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }

                }     
            ]

        }

    }

  }
}
```

Upon running the app, `ruleName` of `ruleList` shows but not the `innerLabel` of `roomList`. The console displays the following message: 
`asset:///SelectARoom.qml:100: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: selRoom`
`asset:///SelectARoom.qml:100: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: selRoom`

i.e., `selRoom` is not in scope for `roomList` (the nested list).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Try `pageSelectARoom.selRoom.modelRoom`?
2. Create alias to `selRoom.modelRoom` at root level and try using that?

Comment: Tried both methods. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a documentation of the `ListView.listItemComponents` property but it looks like some kind of delegate.

If the sub-list is part of the first list's delegate, it might not have access to global variables.
The [QML docs state](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-listview.html#delegate-prop) that delegates can access their position index and the variables of the model only.

Try to access other values outside the delegate's scope like to see whether that works

```
ListView {
    id: roomList
    Component.oncompleted: console.log(ruleList.height)

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it is not very efficient. The following is the new code:

```
Page {
id: pageSelectARoom

property alias currentPage: pageSelectARoom
property string propId

attachedObjects: [
    SelectRoomView {
       id: selRoom 
    }
]

onPropIdChanged: {
    selRoom.propId = propId;
}

Container {
    layout: StackLayout {
    orientation: LayoutOrientation.TopToBottom
}

background: Color.create("#FFFFFF")

ScrollView{   
    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
    objectName: "scrollView"                   

    ListView {
        id: ruleList
        dataModel: selRoom.modelRule

        function getModelMain() {           //the object 'selRoom' is accessible from this function.
             return selRoom.modelRoom;
        }

        listItemComponents: [   
            ListItemComponent {
                id: outerList

                Container{
                    id: ruleContainer

                    function getModel() {        
                        return ruleContainer.parent.getModelMain();  
                    }                       

                    Label {
                        id: outerLabel
                        text: ListItemData.ruleName
                        textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
                        textStyle.color: Color.Black
                    }
                    Label{
                        id: outerId
                        text: ListItemData.ruleId
                        textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
                        textStyle.color: Color.Black
                        visible: true
                    }

                    ListView{
                        id: roomList
                        dataModel: ruleContainer.getModel() 
                        listItemComponents: [

                            ListItemComponent {
                                id: innerList


                                Label{
                                    id: innerLabel
                                    text: ListItemData.name
                                    textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
                                    textStyle.color: Color.Black

                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }

            }     
        ]

    }

   }

  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or is there an alternate more efficient solution? Waiting for response. Thanks.